# Using YQL in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

`enter code here`I am trying to extract content out of a website for learning purposes. I used YQL for that and it gave me JSON back(https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/). I thought I was making progress but unfortunately I was not able to get same output via NPM module. Following is my code:

```
var YQL = require('yql');
new YQL.exec('select * from html where url="http://www.natnlawcenter.com/United-States-Car-Dealerships/Alabama.aspx" ', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

and following is my output:

```
{ query: 
   { count: 1,
     created: '2015-09-27T23:51:25Z',
     lang: 'en-US',
     results: { body: [Object] } } }
```

How do I access content of body:[Object]?

Thanks for your time.

I have modified the code as below:

```
request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.natlawcenter.com/United-States-Car-Dealerships/Alabama.aspx'
}, function(err, response, body) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    // Tell Cherrio to load the HTML
     $ = cheerio.load(body);
    console.log($('td').each(function(i, element){
      var a = $(this);
      console.log(a);
    }));
});
```

and following is my output:

```
{ options: 
   { withDomLvl1: true,
     normalizeWhitespace: false,
     xmlMode: false,
     decodeEntities: true },
  _root: 
   { '0': 
      { type: 'root',
        name: 'root',
        attribs: {},
        children: [Object],
        next: null,
        prev: null,
        parent: null },
     options: 
      { withDomLvl1: true,
        normalizeWhitespace: false,
        xmlMode: false,
        decodeEntities: true },
     length: 1,
     _root: [Circular] },
  length: 0,
  prevObject: 
   { options: 
      { withDomLvl1: true,
        normalizeWhitespace: false,
        xmlMode: false,
        decodeEntities: true },
     _root: { '0': [Object], options: [Object], length: 1, _root: [Circular] },
     length: 0,
     prevObject: { '0': [Object], options: [Object], length: 1, _root: [Circular] } } }
[Function]
[Function]
[Function]
[Function]
[Function]
{ '0': 
   { type: 'tag',
     name: 'td',
     attribs: { valign: 'top', width: '999' },
     children: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     next: 
      { data: '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t',
        type: 'text',
        next: null,
        prev: [Circular],
        parent: [Object] },
     prev: 
      { data: '\r\n\t\t\t',
        type: 'text',
        next: [Circular],
        prev: null,
        parent: [Object] },
     parent: 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'tr',
        attribs: {},
        children: [Object],
        next: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        parent: [Object] } },
-------------------------------
'188': 
   { type: 'tag',
     name: 'td',
     attribs: { width: '25%', icobalt: 'System.Web.UI.ITemplate' },
     children: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ],
     next: 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'td',
        attribs: [Object],
        children: [Object],
        next: [Object],
        prev: [Circular],
        parent: [Object] },
     prev: 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'tr',
        attribs: [Object],
        children: [Object],
        next: [Circular],
        prev: [Object],
        parent: [Object] },
     parent: 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'tbody',
        attribs: {},
        children: [Object],
        next: null,
        prev: null,
        parent: [Object] } },
```

How can I access whats in children object of for example '188'?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: make sure your output is an object NOT string. And then you can access it `your_object.query.results.body`. If you have string output: `JSON.parse(your_string)`

Comment: sure seems like it would be a lot simpler to scrape the whole page yourself and pull what you need out of it using cheerio. With YQL you have to recursivley walk through all of the dom elements as an array of objects

Comment: Never used that. If you dont mind can you please share some sample code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need parse the **JSON** response in to **JS** object using `JSON.parse()`. Your code can we re-written like so -

```
request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.natlawcenter.com/United-States-Car-Dealerships/Alabama.aspx'
}, function(err, response, body) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    if (response.statusCode === 200 && body) return JSON.parse(body);
});
```

Comment: i can't seem to reach the URL you specified so that might be the case why you're getting that error

Comment: http://www.nationallemonlawcenter.com/United-States-Car-Dealerships/Alabama.aspx - here is the URL. Thanks for taking effort in replicating the issue.

Comment: ah, the problem here is your actually requesting a full webpage and not an API endpoint. In this case, I would suggest using a webpage scraper to achieve what you're trying to do. You can look into this one [X-ray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray) with some [example](https://gist.github.com/riyadhalnur/18d395a4f7e9ea21a1b7) here